# Fill in dataframe NULL cells with associated values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to fill in the Null values with values that are already populated with the ColA group

original df:

```
ColA    ColB     ColC
cat      20      blue
cat      28      yellow
fish     32       red
fish     NaN      NaN
fish     NaN      NaN
dog      3       black
dog      311      tan
dog      755     white
frog     NaN      NaN
frog     NaN      NaN
frog     400      green
frog     NaN      NaN
```

Leave alone the rows that have populated cells in each column, but where there are null values, I want to fill those cells with the associated value that the ColA group has populated, for example:

desired df:

```
ColA    ColB     ColC
cat      20      blue
cat      28      yellow
fish     32       red
fish     32       red
fish     32       red
dog      3       black
dog      311     tan
dog      755     white
frog     400     green
frog     400     green
frog     400     green
frog     400     green
```

Any ideas is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `goupby` with forward fill (`ffill`) and back fill(`bfill`)

```
df[['ColB', 'ColC']] = df.groupby('ColA').ffill().bfill()

    ColA   ColB    ColC
0    cat   20.0    blue
1    cat   20.0  yellow
2   fish   32.0     red
3   fish   32.0     red
4   fish   32.0     red
5    dog    3.0   black
6    dog    3.0     tan
7    dog    3.0   white
8   frog  400.0   green
9   frog  400.0   green
10  frog  400.0   green
11  frog  400.0   green
```

Comment: I had some issues with that line - perhaps because my actual data/dataframe isn't as controlled. But df['ColB'] = df.groupby('ColA')['ColB'].fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill') worked for me.. Thanks!